# Using BigInteger to follow algorithm

Tags: java

I tried following the pseudo code given on : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm. This worked for int values, however when I tried to implement the same code except using BigInteger rather than ints; it doesn't ever seem to exit the loop? it will never get to the print statement and will continue running. This makes zero sense to me, as the int implementation which does work is identical except for the type. Anyone notice anything idiotic which I'm doing ? it should work =/ doesn't matter which test values I use, it will run but will just continue running and will never get to the print statement.

```
public void extended_gcd(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
{
    BigInteger[] ans = new BigInteger[3];
    BigInteger[] ans1 = new BigInteger[3];
    //s
    ans[0] = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    //t
    ans[1] = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    //r
    ans[2] = b;

    //old s
    ans1[0] = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    //old t
    ans1[1] = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    //old r
    ans1[2] = a;

    while (!ans[2].equals(0)){
    BigInteger quotient = ans1[2].divide(ans[2]);

    BigInteger temps = ans[0];
    BigInteger tempt = ans[1];
    BigInteger temptr =ans[2];

    ans[2] = ans1[2].subtract(quotient).multiply(temptr);
    ans1[2] = temptr;

    ans[0] = ans1[0].subtract(quotient).multiply(temps);
    ans1[0] = temptr;

    ans[1] = ans1[1].subtract(quotient).multiply(tempt);
    ans1[1] = temptr;

    }

    System.out.println("Bézout coefficients:" + ans1[0] + "," + ans1[1]);
   // System.out.println( "greatest common divisor:", old_r);
   // System.out.println( "quotients by the gcd:", (t, s));
}
```

Comment: `while (!ans[2].equals(0)){` should be `while (!ans[2].equals(BigInteger.ZERO)){`

Comment: How was you int code looking? This `ans[2] = ans1[2].subtract(quotient).multiply(temptr)` is equivalent to `ans[2] = (ans1[2] - quotient) * multiply` not `ans[2] = ans1[2] - quotient * multiply`, the methods are called from left to right, it's no longer an arithmetic expression.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the predicate for the while loop is never satisfied:

```
while (!ans[2].equals(0)){
```

Try comparing to BigInteger.ZERO and see if that helps.

Comment: Fire up a debugger and see which of your assumptions is not being met.  It's been ten minutes since you posted here.  I think it would have taken less time in a debugger.

Comment: Post the solution so you can help others.